# How to make a web request before auth lock screen initialization?

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I want to make a web request (an ajax request) before the initialization of lock screen. Means I want to fetch some data from some remote source before the initialization of lock screen. So does auth0 provides any method like “onInitialize” or like “beforeSend” method of ajax?
By going through this link (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11) I found this:

```
document.getElementById(‘btn-login’).addEventListener(‘click’, function() {
lock.show();
});
```

I think this might also be used but is there any specific method provides by auth0 to do some work before the inilialzation of lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auth0 [Pre-User Registration](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks) hook to make an external HTTP request to fetch data during using signup. 
https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/guides/use-the-pre-user-registration-extensibility-point

For an HTTP request, you can use the request library. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do this on hosted login page (before login screen appears). I am not using angular